# error con Android 12 pide FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE cuando crea los intent

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy felizmente trabajando con mi proyecto FLUTTER para android unicamente. Cuando mi cel donde hago el debug, me pide actualizacíon, la cual acepto, sin pensar en los detalles que iban a salir.

Ahora, mi proyecto no levanta por este inconveniente ::

**Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.**

Alguien que haya pasado por lo mismo que me diga por donde llegarle a la solución.?

Hasta donde llevo detectando::

-> El android a la cual se actualizo fue la versión 12, (API 33 creo), con la version 11 API 31 funciona correctamente.

-> El detalle salta por el uso de paquetes que tienen conexión nativa a android por medio de method channel.

-> El primer paquete es :: sms_user_consent
-> El segundo paquete es:: background_locator

Reitero, todo el proyecto funciona con android 11, correctamente.

He intentado::

-> Aumentar la version de compilación y target.
-> Agregue :: **implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'** y tambien con alpha05 y no funciono.

Ahora estoy checando los paquetes,quizás ya tengan alguna solución por ahí..

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios y/o sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

[ SOLUCIONADO ]

El detalle aparecio en los paquetes, y siguiendo los issues de los paquetes, logre resolver el más importante para mi proyecto y el otro paquete se encuentra en el olvido desde hace un buen tiempo.

Además de lo anterior, toque en mi proyecto:

En el **Android/grandle.properties** agregue:

**android.enableJetifier=true**

En **Android/app/build.gradle** modifique:

**compileSdkVersion 32**

**minSdkVersion 21**
**targetSdkVersion 32**

agregue en las dependencias :

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

En **Android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml** agregue:

Justo debajo del activity principal (**.MainActivity**):

**android:exported="true"**

y listo!.

Toque líneas de un paquete pero eso ya es otra historia.

Muchas gracias a todos los que me apoyaron directa o indirectamente.

Excelente día! y que sus proyectos les compilen....